# Coffeescript 'unspected token' in codepen

Tags: coffeescript, codepen

I am trying to use coffeescript in code pen

Here is the code I want to try:

```
$(document).ready ->
  render()
```

So I have enabled coffeescript in the `js` pane and added `jQuery` as an external javascript:

[image]

However I am getting this error

[image]

I am quite confident the code is valid coffeescript code. So why `codepen` flags 'unexpected token'?

Comment: Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/kongakong/pen/aVzZKy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at all your code:

```
$(document).ready ->
  render()

getWordList = ->
  [['hello', 12], ['dear', 10], ['a', 9], ['Joe', 5], ['8', 2]]

render = ->
  $canva = $('.wordcloud-canvas')
  options =
    list           : getWordList()
    fontFamily     : 'Times, serif'
    weightFactor   : 2
    color          : '#f02222'
    rotateRatio    : 0
    rotationSteps  : 0
    shuffle        : false
    backgroundColor: 'white'
    drawOutOfBound : no
    gridSize       : 320

    window.WordCloud $canvas[0], options
```

We see that the problem is really that line 21 (`window.WordCloud $canvas[0], options`) is indented one step too far. The indentation indicates that the `window.WordCloud` call should be part of the `options` object but that's not valid CoffeeScript. If we paste that into the "Try CoffeeScript" section at http://coffeescript.org/, it even says:

```
[stdin]:19:25: error: unexpected newline
    gridSize       : 320
                        ^
```

If you fix that (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOgLbo) then spurious error message about the `>` goes away and you're left with a simple (and correct) complaint about spelling `$canvas` wrong in the `$canva = $('.wordcloud-canvas')` assignment.

Your code was broken in two ways, CodePen is itself broken in a different way.